# How can I create multiple files on secondary storage using SAF in Kitkat?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, storage-access-framework

From Android 4.4 KitKat, applications cannot access secondary storage completely.

We can use Storage Access Framework to access. If I want to create file, I would need to call the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` intent.

If I want to create multiple files simultaneously, how can I create it? Do I need to call that intent each time?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in KitKat... In the following Android releases, there are tree permissions (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) you might be able to leverage to create multiple files at the same time.

It grants you permission to manage a sub-tree of the entire file system.